# Drawing a tangent to a circle at a given point in just 3 ruler-and-compass constructions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

A friend of mine recently introduced me to an interesting app called [Euclidea](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/euclidea/id927914361?mt=8) that challenges you to complete geometric constructions like the ones we learnt in high school. The app has successfully made me feel quite silly about myself, for I am unable to solve this elementary problem:

> Given a circle and a point on its circumference, construct the tangent to the circle at that point using ruler-and-compass constructions.

[image: problem]

The difficulty I am facing is in finding an optimal solution: I want to accomplish this using as few constructions as possible. So, drawing a line with the ruler would count as one construction, and drawing a circle with the pair of compasses would count as one construction.

I am able to do it in four constructions like this:

[image: solution]

But, apparently there is a solution using just three constructions. And, after several weeks of trying (and failing), I have decided to ask for help. Can anyone help me see the light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Pick an arbitrary point $A$ on the circle, close to $P$, the point of tangency. (0 moves)
2. Draw a circle centred at $A$ passing through $P$ and intersecting the circle again at $B$. (1 move)
3. Draw a circle centred at $P$ passing through $B$. Let it intersect the circle centred at $A$ at $C$. (2 moves)
4. Draw $PC$. (3 moves)